# in java how can ı call a method like this ----->

Tags: java, arrays, input, methods, java.util.scanner

```
public static int menus(String[]items,Scanner input) {}
```

we can call this for first part like that
in main method

```
String[] Array ={"can","car","cam"};
        menus(Array,?);
```

but how can ı call second parameter(scanner input part) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instanciate a `Scanner` and pass it

```
String[] Array = {"can", "car", "cam"};
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
menus(Array, sc);
```